# Getting a psycopg2 `connection` object from pytest-pgsql

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

## Why I am trying to do this

I want to abstract some operations on a database behind a python class called `DataStore`. This will have methods such as `get_last_update_for_user(username: str) -> date` that abstract away the need for anyone using the database to understand any SQL.

I would like the constructor of `DataStore` to take a psycopg2 `connection` object as an argument, and use that to connect to the relevant database. Responsibility for creating the `connection` object will lie with the calling code.

My understanding is that psycopg2 is a performant Postgres database driver for python and a reasonable option for this.

## Testing

I want to have unit tests for methods such as `get_last_update_for_user`, to ensure that my queries are behaving as I expect (particularly for more complex queries). To do so I need to set up a database as a test fixture.

I am trying to do this using pytest-pgsql. My understanding is that this uses psycopg2 as its driver. However, I am not able to work out how to get a psycopg2 `connection` object. I am only able to get SQLAlchemy objects. e.g. the following

```py
import pytest_pgsql


def test_foo(postgresql_db: pytest_pgsql.PostgreSQLTestDB):
    with postgresql_db.engine.connect() as conn:
        print(conn)
        conn.cursor()
```

will print `<sqlalchemy.engine.base.Connection object at 0x7f983aa503a0>` and raise an exception: `AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'cursor'`

## Questions

1. Is it possible to get a psycopg2 `connection` object from `pytest-pgsql`?
2. Is there a different test fixture I should consider instead? (Not keen on `pytest-postgresql` because of the restriction to psycopg version 3.)
3. Is it a design error to pass a connection object from a specific driver to my `DataStore` wrapper class?